# Take Action based on QR code Information of VCARD, iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to handle QR code's Information, As QR code can have any information, For now, I want to handle only

## 1 URL and redirect to safari browser--> its fine

## 2 vCard and open contact book with contact values, But I'm seeing that VCARDS keys name are not unique(not sure if I'm Having improper QR codes). And also, QR value is a string to how to detect which value is for which key of address book?

e.g:

```
"BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Ashwin kanjariya
TEL:+999-999-9999
EMAIL:you@we.com
URL:http://www.youandme.com
N:kanjariya;ashwin
ADR:any address
ROLE:software developer
VERSION:3.0
END:VCARD"
```

So, I'm Not sure for VCARD all keys are universal or not? What is the best way to handle it?

I appreciate your any kind of suggest that can help me to figure out VCARD parsing.

Is CFDataCreate with ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation best way to go with?(I have support for below IOS 9 as well)
like

```
let vCardnsdata = CFDataCreate(nil, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(vCard.bytes), vCard.length)
let addressbookDefaultSrc  = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook)
let vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource.takeUnretainedValue(), vCardData).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
```

Answer (score 1):

VCARD has several versions with slightly different implementations, keys don't have to be unique, a person can have multiple home or work phone numbers for example, but you should be able to tell what is a phone number and just accept as many as your customer believes is reasonable for their use case.

An extensive list of what you may find in VCARD's is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

If you want to make sure that all the data is stored, then you may have to implement lists, or in database terms, store items in different tables so that one to many relationships can be maintained for several items.

When designing a system to store information about people, you may also want to observe some of the [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)